# The value of X is given as 700 rounded to 1.s.f State the upper and lower bound

Tags: upper-lower-bounds, significant-figures

I have completely forgot how to do this and I wasn’t sure whether the lower bound was 600 and upper was 800. Or lower 650 and upper 750

Comment: You have to be more clear, is this question about laboratory data or analysis of numbers? If about laboratory, then I believe that the lower bound must be $650$ and upper bound $750$ (Not including $750$ so $650<=x<750$

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate bounds within which $X$ lies are $749.999\ldots$ and $650$ respectively. More precisely, we have that $$650\le X\lt 750.$$